# How to convert ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer to String?

Tags: ruby

I want to get String object out of ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer. Method to_s returns the same type ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer. Only to_sym.to_s returns String, but this is more of a hack. Here's my console playing:

```
irb(main):008:0> s = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("asdf")
# => "asdf"
irb(main):009:0> s.class
# => ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
irb(main):010:0> s.to_s.class
# => ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
irb(main):011:0> s.to_sym.to_s
# => "asdf"
irb(main):012:0> s.to_sym.to_s.class
# => String
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `SafeBuffer` _is_ a string already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

interpolate it as a string:

```
irb(main):001:0> "#{ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("asdf")}".class
=> String
```

Comment: Thank you! Works best in my case, where sometimes I get nil:
`"#{nil}"` results in empty string, whereas `String.new(nil)` gives an error

Answer (score 46):

There's actually a method for this: [`String#to_str`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_str)

```
buf = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("asdf")

str = buf.to_str #=> "asdf"
str.class        #=> String
```

`String#to_str` works exactly like `String#to_s`: it returns the receiver, converting it to String if necessary. But unlike the overridden [`ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer#to_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html#method-i-to_s) there's no `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer#to_str` so the original method is called.

---

Note that [`ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html) is a subclass of `String`:

```
s = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("asdf")
s.is_a? String
# => true
```

So there's often no need to convert it at all.

Comment: this is totally true, there should not be a need to create safe buffers.

Comment: I needed to do this when something was returning a SafeBuffer in my tests, because CGI.unescapeHTML will break horribly (with 'can't dup NilClass') if it is a SafeBuffer and not a plain string.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I had never seen String#to_str before.  (I had been using Stringe.new(safe_buffer), which also works.)

Comment: Alternative, you could use [to_param](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html#method-i-to_param)

Comment: I needed to do this to insert the value into a string field in a gRPC protobuf message

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I have to supplement that sometimes it's necessary to convert `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` to `String`.

I met this problem when applying `gsub` on an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` object.

```
s = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("asdf")
s.gsub(/a/) { puts $1.present? }
```

`$1` would be always nil. You must convert s to `String` first

```
s = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("asdf")
s.to_str.gsub(/a/) { puts $1.present? }
```

This will return right answer. Even `s.to_s` is not useful here.